Is the martingale property of an exponential implies the martingale property of the process?
It is well-known that under suitable conditions, if $X_t$ is a martingale with quadratic variation $\langle X \rangle_t$, then the process $$Z_t \equiv e^{X_t - \frac{1}{2}\langle X \rangle_t}$$ is  martingale. Is there a converse to this statement? Is it true that if $e^{X_t - \frac{1}{2}Y_t}$ is martingale, then under suitable conditions $X_t$ is a martingale with quadratic variation $Y_t$?

More precisely, if $X$ is a continuous (local) martingale then $Z_t:=e^{X_t-{1\over 2}\langle X\rangle_t}$ is a local martingale. Notice that $Z$ is strictly positive.
(To keep it simple, let's assume $X_0=0$, so that $Z_t=1$.)
Conversely, if $M$ is a strictly positive continuous local martingale with $M_0=1$, then $M_t=e^{K_t-{1\over 2}\langle K\rangle_t}$, where  $K_t:=\int_0^t M^{-1}_s\,dM_s$ is also a continuous local martingale, with quadratic variation $\langle K\rangle_t=\int_0^t M^{-2}_s\,d\langle M\rangle_t$. In particular, if $M$ is known from the outset to be of the form $e^{X_t-{1\over 2}Y_t}$, with $X$ a continuous semimartingale (with decomposition  $X=L+A$,  $L$ being the  local martingale part of $X$) and $Y$ a continuous adapted  process of finite variation, then
$$
e^{X_t-{1\over 2}Y_t}=e^{K_t-{1\over 2}\langle K\rangle_t}
$$
so
$$
K_t-L_t=A_t+{1\over 2}[\langle K\rangle_t-Y_t].
$$
The left side of this equality is a continuous local martingale; the right is a continuous adapted process of finite variation. Therefore both sides are $0$ for all $t$.  Because the left side vanishes at time $0$, so does the right. Therefore
$$
L_t=K_t,
$$
$$
Y_t=\langle K\rangle_t+2A_t=\langle L\rangle_t+2A_t.
$$
In short, if $e^{X_t-{1\over 2}Y_t}$ is a local martingale ($X$ being assumed a continuous semimartingale and $Y$ a continuous adapted process of finite variation) then $Y=2A+\langle X\rangle$, where $A$ is the finite variation component of $X$.

Thank you! So if I know $M_t$ is a martingale, does it imply $A=0$ and $X_t$ is a martingale?

No. For example, if $B_t$ is standard Brownian motion, $X_t:=B_t-t$ and $Y_t:=-t$, then $M_t:=e^{X_t-(1/2)Y_t}$ is a martingale (because it's just $e^{B_t-t/2}$ in disguise), but $X$ isn't a martingale.
